# Highcharts Y axis needs to be on the X axis

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

Im making a bar charts that updates live. I want it to update from right to left so that the newest one apears on the right and pushes the one before to the left. but currently its updating from down to up ( **[video example](https://gyazo.com/59b57529104f242f4acbb2a148da345c)** )

I tried using the [inverted](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted) option on the chart but it did nothing. Any solutions?
Live example on js fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/ascnhf12/9/

these are the high chart options

```
export const liveChart = {
  liveChartInterval: null,
  colors: ['#547fff'],
  chart: {
    height: 170,
    type: 'bar',
    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
    marginRight: 10,
    events: {
      load: function () {

        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
        liveChartInterval = setInterval(function () {
          var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            y = Math.random();
          series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        }, 1000);
      }
    },
    inverted: true
  },

  time: {
    useUTC: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  title: false,
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickPixelInterval: 150
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0,
      width: 1,
      color: '#808080'
    }]
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    data: (function () {
      // generate an array of random data
      var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        i;

      for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
        data.push({
          x: time + i * 1000,
          y: Math.random()
        });
      }
      return data;
    }())
  }]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `column` chart type instead of `bar`:

```
chart: {
    type: 'column',
    ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pthagcw6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.type

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic